# Rspec testing layout

Tags: testing, layout, rspec

How do I test that a specific layout is used in RSpec?  I've tried template.layout, response.layout, and response.should render_template("layout") with no luck.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In rspec 2, in a controller spec, you use render_template as you guessed, but you need to include a path relative to the views directory. So if your layout is app/views/layouts/mylayout.html.erb, your spec looks like this:

```
response.should render_template "layouts/mylayout"
```

Comment: And how do you test that no layout was used. Assume that the controller does 'render :layout => false' for example. How do you test it?

Answer (score 7):

The updated syntax for RSpec 3:

```
expect(response).to render_template(:index) # view
expect(response).to render_template(layout: :application) # layout
```

[RSpec docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/render-template-matcher)

Or if you prefer [@Flov's one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6127481/863846), you can write:

```
expect(response).to render_template(:index, layout: :application)
```

Note that `render_template` delegates to `assert_template`. You can find those docs here: [ActionController assert_template](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TemplateAssertions.html#method-i-assert_template).

Comment: Just a note, this no longer works and also the documentation is savagely out of date.

Answer (score 5):

Also, you can test both, the layout and the action rendering, in a one-liner in rspec-2:

```
response.should render_template(%w(layouts/application name_of_controller/edit))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# rspec-rails-1.3.x for rails-2
describe HomeController do
  describe "the home page" do
    it "should use the :home_page layout" do
      get :index
      response.layout.should == "layouts/home_page"
    end
  end
end

# rspec-2 for rails-3 
describe "GET index" do
  it "renders the page within the 'application' layout" do
    get :index
    response.should render_template 'layouts/application' # layout
    response.should render_template 'index'               # view
  end
end
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/11080d61648aaee51840  I'm on rspec 2, rails 3.  I get a deprecation with response.layout and the suggested template.layout errors.